# Layout in Angular application does not correspond its structure

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have an angular app and found that it has a wrong layout behavior which does not correspond to the planned structure. Bellow is the code:

index.html contains the following code:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
      Something is here
    </footer>
    
</body>
```

app.component.html contains the following:

```
<div>
  toolbar is here
...
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And then I have a main component:

```
<h1>Main component starts here</h1> 
<div>
  Something for the main component
 </div>
 <h1>Main component finishes here</h1>
```

As a result I expect to see the following structure:

1. toolbar

2.1 Main component starts here

2.2 main component

2.3 Main component finishes here

3. footer

But I see the wrong order of the components:

1. toolbar

2.1. Main component starts here

2.3. Main component finishes here

3. footer

2.2. Main component

Why footer is not displayed as a last component here? Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: can you add your style files and component ts code in the question

Answer (score 0):

What happen if you try to move you footer code inside the *app.component.html* so that:

- *index.html* will look like this:

```
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

- *app.component.html* will look like this:

```
<div> toolbar is here </div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer> Something is here</footer>
```

Comment: it's the same, no difference...